# how to use class function in simple php file without including just like web.php file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I know there is somewhere `laravel` including or requiring the Route class, that is why we are able to use `Route::get()` in `routes/web.php`. As a beginner I am curious how that is happening, as I am trying to build my own little mvc  :)

Comment: It is basically autoloaded.

Comment: in short you're asking *what's the code to make the thing I need* . That's not the type of questions SO is made to ask for. If you have a specifc need or you have an issue with your code in to reach the desired result post your code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to look at PHP namespaces

[W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_namespaces.asp)

or here

[PHP website](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Once you namespace your files, you can the use the

`use`

keyword to the include the classes that you have namespaced. For example, in Laravel when we

`use App\Models\User`

We are basically saying the current class we are in, can access the functions and variables in the App\Models\User class based on the scope of the class or variable, that is "protected, private and public" access modifiers.

You need to check a bit more about OOP(Object Oriented Programming) techniques to grasp it easily.

All the best with building your MVC.